# findstr not working as expected

Tags: cmd, notepad++, findstr

I am trying to find last line in a text file using the regex  `^.*\z`, it's working fine in notepad++ but when I try it in cmd using `findstr /R "^.*^Z" file.txt` not working.

Comment: May **findstr** command does not support such **regex** as **notepad++** does

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt window and run `findstr /?`. The output help explains what **FINDSTR** supports. The regular expression feature is limited in **FINDSTR**. It does not support all the features as supported by [Boost Perl Regular Expression library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) used by many text editors in various versions.

This batch code could be used to get last non empty line from a file assigned to an environment variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LastLine="

if exist "file.txt" for /F "usebackq eol= delims=" %%# in ("file.txt") do set "LastLine=%%#"

echo Last line is: "%LastLine%"
endlocal
```

Command **FOR** skips all empty lines and by default also all lines starting with a semicolon. For that reason `eol=` is used to define form-feed control character as end of line. In case of last line of file surely never starts with `;` it would be best to remove `eol=` from the **FOR** command line.

In case of file to process always has at least X lines, it would make sense to add to the **FOR** options after `usebackq` the option `skip=X` to skip the first X lines of the file for faster processing.

For details on command **FOR** open a command prompt window and run `for /?`.